# Create App ID, Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, app-store

Do I need a website to create BundleID, or can I use something else instead of.
Usually BundleID are the reverse of domain combined with the app name: com.domanName.appname
Should the domain have a valid website, or can I use some free domains that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

The domain does not have to be an actual domain. So you can use any domain name that you like even if that is not an actual website.

Answer (score 1):

App ID and Build Identifier are set in Developer Account. There is no need to create or have a website.

You can simple create App Id as for e.g. "News App" and Bundle Identifer as "com.newsapp", it will work.

Set as per your requirement and according to application and enjoy!!!